# What is runtime of operator in k8s? The operator in k8s is a docker process?

Tags: kubernetes

What is runtime of operator in k8s? The operator in k8s is a docker process ?
What is runtime of operator in k8s? The operator in k8s is a docker process ?

Comment: What do you mean by "runtime" in this context? An operator can be developed in any programming language, it interacts with the Kubernetes APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to container runtime.  if yes kubernetes supports different [runtimes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) you can choose one of them while creating Kubernetes
cluster.